# State doesn't get updated after the input passes validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-hooks

Inside a Login function (which is triggered by an onClick), I'm using a validation function which tests the email from the input and returns a boolean. If the email doesn't pass the validation the first time, on the next try even if the input is valid the error state doesn't get updated.

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
 const emailValid = validateEmail(email);
 console.log(emailValid)
 if (emailValid) {
   setError('')
   const response = await getAuthToken();
   localStorage.setItem('OauthToken',response.access_token)
 } else {
   setError("Invalid Email")
   console.log(error)
 }
}
```

Comment: you are probably experience a stale closure, is this function defined in the body of the component?

Comment: Yes it is. And it is being called in the child component.